# Standard controller and extension method with same name

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, extension

Provided you have a Visualforce page that uses both a standard controller and an extension class. The extension class has a method with the same name as a method in the standard controller

(i.e, `public save()`)

If you have the following button in your page:

`<apex:commandButton value ="save" action="{!save}" />`

will this call the method from the standard controller or the extension?

Comment: Refer to the link where it has been already answered. A suggestion here -- the easiest and best way is to write a quick PoC and review the results in such scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any extension methods take precedence over controller methods with the same name. Take a look at [Building a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm):

> Multiple controller extensions can be defined for a single page through a comma-separated list. This allows for overrides of methods with the same name. For example, if the following page exists:
>
> ```
> <apex:page standardController="Account"
>     extensions="ExtOne,ExtTwo" showHeader="false">
>     <apex:outputText value="{!foo}" />
> </apex:page>
> ```
>
> with the following extensions:
>
> ```
> public class ExtOne {
>     public ExtOne(ApexPages.StandardController acon) { }
>
>     public String getFoo() {
>         return 'foo-One';
>     }
> }
> public class ExtTwo {
>     public ExtTwo(ApexPages.StandardController acon) { }
>  
>     public String getFoo() {
>         return 'foo-Two';
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The value of the `<apex:outputText>` component renders as foo-One. **Overrides are defined by whichever methods are defined in the “leftmost” extension, or, the extension that is first in the comma-separated list**. Thus, the getFoo method of ExtOne is overriding the method of ExtTwo.

If you have exactly one extension defined, it is "leftmost".